# User confirm before update db

Tags: php, html

Problem is: run confirm user request before to update db. Two choices : using `submitfunc` on click I am able to run js confirm , get the user choice but in `upload_db` function I can't catch the value entered by the user ( it's textarea value)
If I use `button type="submit...` I can get textarea value but I don't how to run confirm and to get confirm returned value before to update db. How can I fix this?

```
<?php
session_start();
// In case user press button_lookfor
if (isset($_POST['button_lookfor'])) {
    // I run sql select...
}
//  In case user press button_update
if (isset($_POST['button_update'])) {
    //to update db i have to get value of textarea.Ok in this case
    $sql_upd = "UPDATE db SET field_value ='" .$_POST['alpha_9_10']."'";
}

function upload_db(){
    //I am not able to catch the value entered in textarea
    if (isset($_POST['alpha_9_10'])) {
        //....
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function submitFunc(){
    var r = confirm("Press OK per confermare la modifica al database!");
    if (r == true) {
        var x="<?php upload_db(); ?>";
        alert(x);
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
</style>
<body>

<form method="post" action="" >
<table class='table1' id="pos_table1" >
    <tr><td><textarea name="alpha_9_10"<textarea></td></tr>
</table>

<button type="submit" name="button_lookfor" >Look for data</button>
<button type="submit name="button_update" >Save data</button>
<!--<button type="button" onClick="submitFunc();"name="button_update">Save</button>-->

</body>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Please format your code, but I would say fix your textarea tag first.

Comment: The problem is you are trying to catch the value of the textarea using php but the php code doesn't do anything until you submit the form. PHP is server side code. What do you want to do with the textarea value? You can get the value with javascript. Also, as WheatBeak said, your code has a lot of syntax problems.

Comment: PHP only runs on the server, javascript runs in the browser. You cannot get javascript to call a PHP function like that. You may need to learn AJAX

Answer (score 0):

You can try returning a confirm value(true or false when a user clicks on the button). The form will only be submitted if user presses ok. this would look something like:

```
<?php
session_start();
// In case user press button_lookfor
if (isset($_POST['button_lookfor'])) {
    // I run sql select...
}
//  In case user press button_update
if (isset($_POST['button_update'])) {
    //to update db i have to get value of textarea.Ok in this case
    $sql_upd = "UPDATE db SET field_value ='" .$_POST['alpha_9_10']."'";
}

function upload_db(){
    //I am not able to catch the value entered in textarea
    if (isset($_POST['alpha_9_10'])) {
        //....
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>

</head>
</style>
<body>

<form method="post" action="" >
<table class='table1' id="pos_table1" >
    <tr><td><textarea name="alpha_9_10"<textarea></td></tr>
</table>

<button type="submit onClick="return confirm('Press OK per confermare la modifica al database!')" name="button_update" >Save data</button>


</body>
</form>
</html>
```